# How to show slippage in MS Project 2016?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2016

Probably a noddy question, but need to ask.  I'd like to be able to demonstrate real time slippage on my plan, for remodeling impact purposes.  I have both original baseline dates and current dates added to my plan.  Is there a way of linking these to show a separate column with real time, total days slippage

Answer (score 1):

In the ribbon, open the "Baseline" drop-down menu and click on Baseline. You will be able to make visual comparisons--for each task--between the Gantt bars for the current plan versus the baseline.

Answer (score 0):

Open up your Finish Variance column.  It calculates gap between Finish Date and Baseline Finish Date.